# C#で個別のFrame内のDocmentを取得するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dom

## 概要

次のような構造を持つオブジェクト内のFrameのDocumentの内容（★印）を取得したいです。

```
wbm
  Control
  currentDocument
  Document
    Window
      Frames
        htmlFramesCollection2
          Document
            Body
              InnerHtml
  m_MRE
  WebBrowser
    base
    Document
      Body
        ★InnerHtml
    Application
      Document
        frames
          body
            InnerHtml
```

htmlFramesCollection2内にFrameがある場合は`currentDocument.Window.Frames[name].Document`のような形で取得できているのですが、新規にIEで開いてしまうウィンドウをWebBrowserで開く下記のような形で拡張しているため、目的のFrameはWebBrowser内にあります。

```
public class ExtendedWebBrowser : WebBrowser
    {
        private AxHost.ConnectionPointCookie cookie;
        private WebBrowser2EventHelper helper;
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [DispIdAttribute(200)]

    public object Application
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ActiveXInstance == null)
            {
                throw new AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException("Application", AxHost.ActiveXInvokeKind.PropertyGet);
            }
            return this.ActiveXInstance.GetType().InvokeMember("Application", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, this.ActiveXInstance, null);


        }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [DispIdAttribute(552)]
    public bool RegisterAsBrowser
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ActiveXInstance == null)
            {
                throw new AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException("RegisterAsBrowser", AxHost.ActiveXInvokeKind.PropertyGet);
            }
            return (bool)this.ActiveXInstance.GetType().InvokeMember("RegisterAsBrowser", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, this.ActiveXInstance, null);


        }
        set
        {
            if (this.ActiveXInstance == null)
            {
                throw new AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException("RegisterAsBrowser", AxHost.ActiveXInvokeKind.PropertySet);
            }
            this.ActiveXInstance.GetType().InvokeMember("RegisterAsBrowser", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, this.ActiveXInstance, new object[] { value });
        }
    }

    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void CreateSink()
    {
        base.CreateSink();
        helper = new WebBrowser2EventHelper(this);
        cookie = new AxHost.ConnectionPointCookie(this.ActiveXInstance, helper, typeof(DWebBrowserEvents2));
    }

    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void DetachSink()
    {
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            cookie.Disconnect();
            cookie = null;
        }
        base.DetachSink();
    }

    public event WebBrowserNewWindow2EventHandler NewWindow2 = (o, e) => { };

    protected virtual void OnNewWindow2(WebBrowserNewWindow2EventArgs e)
    {
        NewWindow2(this, e);
    }

    private class WebBrowser2EventHelper : StandardOleMarshalObject, DWebBrowserEvents2
    {
        private ExtendedWebBrowser parent;

        public WebBrowser2EventHelper(ExtendedWebBrowser parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void NewWindow2(ref object ppDisp, ref bool cancel)
        {
            var e = new WebBrowserNewWindow2EventArgs(ppDisp);
            this.parent.OnNewWindow2(e);
            ppDisp = e.ppDisp;
            cancel = e.Cancel;
        }
    }
}

public delegate void WebBrowserNewWindow2EventHandler(object sender, WebBrowserNewWindow2EventArgs e);

public class WebBrowserNewWindow2EventArgs : CancelEventArgs
{
    public object ppDisp { get; set; }

    public WebBrowserNewWindow2EventArgs(object ppDisp)
    {
        this.ppDisp = ppDisp;
    }
}

[ComImport, Guid("34A715A0-6587-11D0-924A-0020AFC7AC4D")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FHidden)]
public interface DWebBrowserEvents2
{
    [DispId(251)]
    void NewWindow2([InAttribute(), OutAttribute(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] ref object ppDisp, [InAttribute(), OutAttribute()] ref bool cancel);
}
```

下記は使用する側のコードです。

```
private void WebBrowser_NewWindow2(object sender, WebBrowserNewWindow2EventArgs e)
    {
        // 新しい WebBrowser の初期化
        WebBrowser = new ExtendedWebBrowser();
        WebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Control.Controls.Add(WebBrowser);

        var tabPage = new TabPage();

        // 新しい WebBrowser に表示させる設定
        e.ppDisp = this.WebBrowser.Application;
        WebBrowser.RegisterAsBrowser = true;
        WebBrowser.NewWindow2 += WebBrowser_NewWindow2;
    }
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx)に

> An HTML document may contain frames, which are different windows inside of the WebBrowser control. Each frame displays its own HTML page. The Frames collection is available through the Window property.

という記述があり、Window下にないとアクセスできないのではないかと思うのですが、WebBrowser内にWindowプロパティがなく扱えていません…

## Frameの構造

```
<FRAMESET id=FRAMESET2 onload=SetLoadFlg() border=0 frameBorder=0 rows=300px,*,40px><FRAME noResize src="/hoge/html/hogehoge.html" name=M1 scrolling=no><FRAME noResize src="/web21/execJ/servlet/ACH99OMCL_WEBCNTL?_W_SubFname=M2" name=M2><FRAME noResize src="/moge/html/mogemoge.html" name=M3 ></FRAMESET>
```

## 動作環境

・.NET Frame Work 4.5
・Visual Studio2013

## 目的

サイト上のFrame内のDocumentを取得した上で、その中のリンク要素を拾ってサイト内の遷移を勧めたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebBrowser.Documentプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=vs.100).aspx)から辿れるクラスは全てCOMをラップしたものに過ぎず、提供されていない機能にアクセスしたい場合はアンマネージインターフェイスへのポインターからアクセスする必要があります。
これらオブジェクトはDOMを表すものですが、DOMはセキュリティのためフレームを超えてアクセスすることができないよう制限されています。
これを回避するためにはDOM外からアクセスする必要があります。具体的には

1. `HtmlDocument.GetElementById()`などで目的のフレームの要素（`HtmlElement`）を取得する
2. `HtmlElement.DocElement`からアンマネージインターフェイスへのポインターを得る
3. アンマネージインターフェイスへのポインターから`IHTMLFrameBase2`インターフェイスを得る
4. `IHTMLFrameBase2.contentWindow`プロパティで`IHTMLWindow2`インターフェイスを得る
5. `IHTMLWindow2`インターフェイスから`IServiceProvider`インターフェイスを得る
6. `IServiceProvider.QueryService`メソッドに引数`IID_IWebBrowserApp`と`IID_IWebBrowser2`を渡すことで`IWebBrowser2`インターフェイスを得る
7. `IWebBrowser2.Document`プロパティで`IHTMLDocument`インターフェイスを得る

以上のステップでフレームに読み込まれたHTMLのDOMにアクセスできます。
しかし、ステップ2.の時点で.NETオブジェクトではなくCOMインターフェイスですし、最終的に得られるのもCOMインターフェイスですので、その後のDOMアクセスも引き続きCOMインターフェイスを操作する必要があります。

コードを提示することもできますが、ほとんどCOM定義に終始することになるのであまり意味があるとも思えません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
C#歴が1ヶ月にも満たずご回答いただいた内容をこれから調べつつ実装するのですが、[こちら](http://schima.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/06/06/133134)のサイトのような実装になるイメージでしょうか…？

Comment: @ToshinoriSugita はいそんな感じです。ほとんどC#ではない部分を無理やり操作しているので、C#で実装する意義があるのか怪しいところです。